# Laravel: How to extend default paginator by adding the item number?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-pagination

I'm trying to add the item number in a table that has pagination:
[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgxvz.png)

To accomplish that, I placed an 'offset' in the controller and send it back to the view: [paginationOffset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBZkR.png)

It works but I'm trying to refactor that code in the controllers to avoid repetition. I saw some examples adding a macro to the `Support\Collection` and manually instantiating the `LengthAwarePaginator`. Tried it but couldn't make it work with an 'offset'.

How do you recommend to refactor it without placing the logic on the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paginator does more than just pass back the records, it comes with many helper methods.

You can check them out in the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

So for example you could use `$results->firstItem()`

Which will 'Get the result number of the first item in the results.'

It comes with many variables also out of the box:-

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: thanks @ColinMD, it does the trick. I was able to use `$loop->iteration + $contacts->firstItem() - 1` on the template to achieve the same result. Any way to extract that logic out of the template in some kind of helper method?

Comment: You probably can but I've never tried.  You could catch the paginate() and dd() it out to see what it passes back in the controller.  It depends on if Laravel passes back all the paginator methods and variables.